# А почему у меня не подсвечивается код в комментариях?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, комментарии, подсветка-синтаксиса

Хочу в комментариях сделать разметку текста таким образом, чтобы это выглядело `кодом.` И надо сказать, что у меня уже который раз это не получается. 
[image: Первоисточник вопроса]
[Адрес страницы.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539654/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-ios)
Я проверял, это именно свойство отображения сайта, а не свойство моего браузера. 
Вопрос прост: поддерживается ли код в комментариях и как его правильно размечать? Судя по моему опыту разметка из запятых сверху не срабатывает.

Comment: `-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{ `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что нужно убирать пробел сразу после **`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
` -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{ `
```

Должно было быть так

`-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{`

Comment: `Вас понял. Пробую`

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо